# In Bayesian estimation, when can regression coefficients and scale parameter be jointly identifiable? When not?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, probit, identifiability

Exercise 14.2 in Koop, Poirier and Tobias's book (i.e. Bayesian econometric methods) talks about the case that in probit model, the regression and scale parameter are not jointly identified.

I wonder, in general, is there any rules or heuristics that can help us to judge when regression coefficients and scale parameter can be jointly identifiable and when not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some thoughts on the matter:

Consider the latent variable motivation for the probit regression. I'm going to be notationally sloppy here for the sake of brevity, hopefully you can see how it fits into a more rigorous derivation in the textbook. Consider the $i^{th}$ response $y_i$ and the underlying the unobserved random variable $y^*_i$ with predictor variable vector X and parameter vector $\theta$. Typically we assume $y^*_i = \theta^T*X_i + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon ~ N(0, \sigma_e$. Note the use of vector multiplication to represent the linear combination.

Then, the likelihood is derived from the following $Pr(y_i = 1) = Pr(y^*_i + \epsilon > 0 ) = \phi((\theta^T*X_i)/\sigma_e)$, where $\phi$ is the normal CDF. I'm skipping a few steps for brevity. We can see that in this case, if we increase $\sigma_e$ by a constant we can scale down the $\theta$ accordingly and get the same value to input into $\phi$. Thus, we need to fix $\sigma_e$ for our likelihood to make sense, hence it is not jointly identifiable. If instead of a linear combination of predictors and model parameters we had a different function (i.e. affine) this label switching may not occur.